# MacBook Air M1 bluetooth connectivity issue

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, monterey, apple-silicon

I am a new MacBook user, bought MacBook Air M1 about 10 months ago. At first everything was great, bluetooth connection was working fine. But since a couple of months, I began to face bluetooth connectivity issues. I'm not sure whether it is due to the upgrade from BigSur to Monterey.

**Specs:**

1. Model: MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
2. OS: macOS Monterey 12.4
3. Memory: 8GB
4. SSD: 256GB

**Issue:**

I have two bluetooth devices -

1. JBL Live 300TWS earbuds
2. MIVI Roam 2 speaker.

Previously both of them used to work perfectly fine. But now, they disconnect immediately after 1-2 seconds of connecting. I can even hear "Paired" sound from my speaker but gets disconnected immediately. Keep in mind that I'm NOT trying to connect both at a time. At first I thought there was an issue with my devices, but after testing with couple of Android phones, I'm sure the issue is with the MacBook.

**Things tried:**

1. Turn Off/On Bluetooth in MacBook, Turn Off/On my bluetooth device
2. Forget all devices in MacBook and connecting them again
3. Deleted ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX.plist
4. Deleted /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
5. sudo pkill bluetoothd
6. Force quit bluetoothd from Activity Monitor
7. Force quit coreaudiod from Activity Monitor (saw this somewhere)
8. Turn off Wifi

I even restarted the MacBook after every step but still wont work.

I'm out of almost all the options and only thing I have now is to try downgrading to BigSur but the process is too hard for me and I don't have any previous backup.

Are there any other ways to fix this? What do I do?

Comment: When forgetting paired devices did you also reinitialized the Bluetooth devices.  This may help, especially when your are also using Bluetooth devices with phones. (Even if it perfectly works on phone)

Comment: Yes! I did, but it still doesn't work.